# jQuery toggle with different buttons/links

Tags: jquery, toggle

I´m using this easy jQuery toggle:
http://bit.ly/YoRRXc (fiddle)

But I want that on click on "Toggle2" that it will do the same as click on "Toggle".

So for example:

- click on "Toggle" --> Sidebar slides away
- click on "Toggle 2" --> Sidebar comes in

Is that possible? And how?

Regards,
Marc

Comment: instead of same Ids, use class name and use . selector with class name

Comment: that´s not the solution, because then I have to click twice on "Toggle2" when clicked on "Toggle" before :/ demo: http://bit.ly/10W22A9

Comment: I haven't provided you any solution, i just suggest you a nice approach you should use and i also mark same comment to wrong answer earlier provided by one user which is deleted now. I am working for solution .

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('.toggle').click(function () {
    if($('#A').width()==0)
    {
        $('#A').animate({
            width: 200
        });
        $('#B').animate({
            left: 200
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#A').animate({
            width: 0
        });
        $('#B').animate({
            left: 0
        });

    }

});
```

[working JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/6FMZY/669/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id='A'></div>
<div id='B'> 
    <a href='javascript:' class='toggle'>Toggle</a><br> 
    <a href='javascript:' class='toggle'>Toggle2</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    var leftVal = $('#B').offset().left;
    var setLeft = leftVal == '0' ? "200px" : "0";
    $('#A').animate({width:'toggle'});
    $('#B').animate({left: setLeft});
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6FMZY/670/)**</kbd>